# Images are stacked and slow loading on first page load

Tags: image, loading, pagespeed, image-gallery

I'm using shuffle.js for a gallery on a static site of about 100 images, each at about 100-500K.  Every time the page loads, the images display stacked on top of one another and load very slowly.  I usually have to refresh or select the next filterable category to get them to display correctly.  Any ideas on how to resolve this / suggestions for image optimization?

I appended "loading=lazy" to the img tags in the html but it had little to no effect.

Here is the problematic page: https://scotlandpaintingco.com/our-work.html

Thank you for any suggestions!